# Program not running using existing python virtual environment in intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, import, virtual-environment, pythoninterpreter

Since last many months I was using intellij idea comfortably but suddenly something went wrong and all my existing projects are not running now. I have the python virtual environment in SDK section along with all the libraries. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMw1g.png) but then also my programs are not working at all. [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck9Bi.png)

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM86K.png)

some days back All these programs were working perfectly fine. I need help. This is very frustrating.

Comment: looks like you `venv` has not been activated

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is not enough information to provide a proper solution. Please get in touch with IDE support via Help | Contact support...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).